# Issue with color using ProgressBar.setProgressDrawable

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am appending progressbar in elements of a list and also dynamically updating that progressbar.
But the odd situation that i m facing is that..

When i have more than one element in my list and i change the color of progressbar by using `Progressbar.setProgressDrwable(),`   all progressbars in the list are updated and their color is changed as desired.

But when I have only one single element in the list this method doesn't work, All I can see the background of my progressbar not the color.

I have also created my XML file for progressbar's background and color but than also its not working.

My XMl code for ProgressDrawable is

FirstColor.xml

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="15dip" />
        <gradient android:startColor="#A9A9A9" android:centerColor="#A9A9A9"
            android:endColor="#A9A9A9" android:angle="90" />
        <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#A9A9A9" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
     <scale  android:scaleGravity="left" android:scaleWidth="100%" >
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="15dip" />
            <gradient android:startColor="#ADFF2F" android:centerColor="#ADFF2F"
                android:endColor="#ADFF2F" android:angle="90" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#ADFF2F" />
        </shape>
    </scale>
</item>
```

SecondColor.xml

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="15dip" />
        <gradient android:startColor="#A9A9A9" android:centerColor="#A9A9A9"
            android:endColor="#A9A9A9" android:angle="90" />
        <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#A9A9A9" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <scale android:scaleGravity="left" android:scaleWidth="100%" >
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="15dip" />
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFBF00" android:centerColor="#FFBF00"
                android:endColor="#FFBF00" android:angle="90" />
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#FFBF00" />
        </shape>
    </scale>
</item>
```

and the java code that i m using to change the color of progressbar is

progressbar1.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.FirstColor));
                    progressbar1.setProgress(amntPercentage.intValue());

progressbar1.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.SecondColor));
                    progressbar1.setProgress(amntPercentage.intValue());

If anyone out there can solve my problem it would be a great help..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before setting the new `progressDrawable` and setting the `progressvalue`, make sure that you have not setted the `progressvalue` to '0'.
This happens because in `style.xml` for progressbar we define the xml fields only for start, middle and end; not for '0'.

I setted the progressvalue to '1' before changing the drawable and my project is working fine.